# ( Ask ) Create pagination in mongodb with simple query php?

Tags: mongodb, pagination, paging

( Ask ) How to create pagination in mongodb with simple query php ?

Thanks for best answer .

Comment: ( Comment ) Sorry, this is too broad for Stack Overflow.  ( Clarification ) If you make some attempt and get stuck we'll be happy to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

using skip() and limit() methods.
Code:

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
$cursor->limit(10)->skip(20);
```